# How to move found files to another directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, mv

Hello to everyone I have the following script that works fine except the mv argument. The script basically searching for the files that were created at a specific time and the I need to move all of the founded files to another directory with the name `timefile`

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -rp 'hour ([0]0-23): ' hour
case $hour in
  (0|00)
    find /home/mikepnrs -newermt "yesterday 23:59" \
      ! -newermt 0:59 ;;
  (0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])
    find /home/mikepnrs -newermt "$((10#$hour-1)):59" \
      ! -newermt "$hour:59" | mv -t /home/mikepnrs/timefile ;;
  (*)
    printf 'invalid hour: %s\n' "$hour"
esac
```

The syntax `mv -t /home/mikepnrs/timefile` seems not to be working. Error that I get is mv missing the file operand.

Any solutions?

Comment: i guess it should be `mv -t /home/mikepnrs/timefile $(find /home/mikepnrs -newermt "$((10#$hour-1)):59"  ! -newermt "$hour:59"` take a look at `man mv`

Comment: ^^ don't do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your pipe (`find ... | mv ...`) means sending STDOUT of `find` to STDIN of `mv`. But `mv` does not accept files from STDIN, only arguments.

You *could* translate STDIN to arguments using `xargs`:

```
find ... -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t target
```

(`-print0` and `xargs -0` to pipe null-delimited instead of newline-delimited output, because newline is a valid character as part of filenames).

But **preferred option** is to simply use `find -exec`:

```
find ... -exec mv -t target {} +
```

In your case:

```
find /home/mikepnrs -newermt "$((10#$hour-1)):59" \
  ! -newermt "$hour:59" -exec mv -t /home/mikepnrs/timefile {} +
```

---

Disclaimer: I did not check the rest of your script.

Comment: Used it: ' find /home/mikepnrs -newermt "$((10#$hour-1)):59" \
      ! -newermt "$hour:59" exec  mv -t target  {/home/mikepnrs/timefile} + ;; ' and had the following error.
find: paths must precede expression: `exec'

Comment: you're missing `-` before `exec`. And `/home/mikepnrs/timefile` is the target, and `{}` must be literally exactly that.

Comment: @pLumo the `;;` is still needed to terminate the `case` I think?

Comment: Totally true, sry. Like I said I did not look at the rest of the code^^ I usually put the `;;` in the next line, confused me :-D